# show scheduled posts in the calendar

Tags: blog-page

I am creating a WordPress site for a school so if I put a future post for when the school will re-open it won't show until that date I would like it to show in the calendar in advance is there away around the scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

The `WP_Query` class has the [`post_status` parameter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#status-parameters), you could leverage the `future` status.